# Need to understand how microservices architecture work

Tags: architecture, microservices

I have a doubt regarding the microservices, although I know the concept of microservices and also new to microservices, it provides load balancing through ribbon, client discovery  etc,
What I want to know is since now a days clusters gives same kind of functionality like load balancing, fault tolerance(ex. Kuberntes),  when we are deploying microservices on clusters do we need to deploy Eureka server, Eureka client, ribbon, etc or what we should deploy or what should not, since clusters gives all these functionality so where to use these microservices features if deploying on clusters

Comment: To make your question clearer, maybe you can split the two concepts (Microservice architecture and "clusters"). Kubernetes is a container orchestration system and you can have a microservice architecture with or without Kubernetes.

Comment: Hi @Seth is there anything which I can refer to understand the microservices architecture with or without kubernets for production level environment.
and what are the do's and don'ts, and how and  where i can use eureka discovery, ribbon etc features

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a set of Microservice architecture patterns. The patterns explain the problems you will encounter when implementing Microservice architecture and they provide some common solutions.

Eureka is a solution for service discovery / service registry while Ribbon is a client side library that helps you to manage your inter-process communications (but note that Ribbon is now under maintenance mode, Netflix is going with gRPC).

For a general overview of Microservice architecture, I recommend [this article](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html). 
For more specific information on service management (Why do I need something like Eureka?), you can take a look at [service registry](https://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html). 
For more specific information on communication styles (Why do I need something like Ribbon?), you can take a look at [communication styles](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/rpi.html).